# JButtons not appearing when added

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe, jbutton

Jbutton will not display on screen, and if I try to add from main frame I  get a null pointer exception.

I have followed steps from other examples and problems but none seem to display the JButton, I have tried to add it directly to the main JFrame (which is where I am trying to add it) with Display.getFrame().add(buttons.get(id)); but that just gives me a nullpointer exception for some reason

this is my Display class

https://pastebin.com/Bq0VVL9v
the method which I think might be why I cant add the buttons properly  v

```
private void createDisplay() {

    frame = new JFrame(title);

    frame.setSize(width, height);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setResizable(false);

    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    frame.setVisible(true);

    canvas = new Canvas();

    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));

    canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

    canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

    canvas.setFocusable(false);
    
    frame.add(canvas);
    frame.pack();
}
```

and this is the class I am trying to add buttons with, the button manager which is being called by one of my menu classes

https://pastebin.com/bUMvnmFf

```
public ButtonManager(Icon image,Icon image2, int positionX, int positionY,int width, int height, int id, String name) {

    buttons.add(id, new JButton(name, image));

    buttons.get(id).setRolloverIcon(image2);

    buttons.get(id).setLocation(positionX, positionY);

    buttons.get(id).setSize(width, height);

    System.out.println(buttons.get(0));

    add(buttons.get(id));
}
```

I would have expected the Jbutton to be displayed on screen but that does not happen,  the most annoying thing is the nullpointer if I add() to the the main JFrame in Display class.

EDIT:
another major problem was the canvas was being rendered over the buttons, so none would show up

Comment: As long as I understand you want to create a Factory of Buttons, I think this is the purpose of the class ButtonManager and you want to invoke and put them on the Frame of the Display class, right?

Comment: What's a `Handler`? NVM, make it clear by making an  [edit] to add a [mre].

Comment: @sirandy yes I want to be able to make as many buttons as needed in different states of the game, in my gamestate/gameplay class I want to have a pause button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for you. I codified only the basics for the example, you can continue with the program as you need.

```
/* Button Manager Class */
package mainpackage.display;    

import java.util.ArrayList;    

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;    

public class ButtonManager extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    

    public ArrayList<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();
    Display display;    

    public static JButton getJButton(String name) {
        //Put all your stuff of images and ids here
        JButton aButton = new JButton(name);
        return aButton;
    }    

    public static void putButton(JPanel panel, JButton button, int posX, int posY) {
        button.setLocation(posX, posY);
        panel.add(button);
    }    

    public void remove(int id) {
        buttons.remove(id);
        display.getFrame().remove(buttons.get(id));
    }    

    public void tick() {    

    }    

    public void render() {    

    }    

}
```

Display class:

```
package mainpackage.display;
import java.awt.Canvas;    

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;    

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;    

import static mainpackage.display.ButtonManager.*;

public class Display {

    private JFrame frame;
    private Canvas canvas;

    private String title;
    private int width, height;

    public Display(String title, int width, int height) {
        this.title = title;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        createDisplay();
    }

    private void createDisplay() {
        frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        canvas = new Canvas();

        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        canvas.setFocusable(false);
        frame.add(canvas);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        //You can add many buttons as you need
        putButton(panel, getJButton("Button 1"), 100, 200);
        putButton(panel, getJButton("Button 2"), 800, 800);

        frame.setContentPane(panel);

        frame.pack();
    }

    public void postCreate(Component a) {
        frame.add(a);
    }
    public void postCreate(JButton j) {
        frame.add(j);
    }
    public Canvas getCanvas() {
        return canvas;
    }
    public JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display("Hello", 1000, 1000);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ButtonManager never initializes `Display`, so:
`display.getFrame().add(buttons.get(id));` will NPE as display is null.

It seems ButtonManager does not need the reference to Display.

On another level, adding the button to the frame conflicts with the Canvas object.

I wrote this main method and it displays both the canvas and button:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display("title", 200, 200);

    ButtonManager buttonManager = new ButtonManager(... , 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, "name");

    display.getFrame().getContentPane().add(buttonManager, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    display.getFrame().pack();
  }
```

And the Canvas adding code was modified to (note the last two lines):

```
    canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    canvas.setFocusable(false);

    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(canvas, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the class `Display` which is your main frame, it appears you did not add an instance of your panel, that is `ButtonManager` class. Or was that done in another separate class that was not included here?